# Black screen after Windows logo. What is happening to my machine?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, bluetooth, sleep, malware

I downloaded a PDF version of a book from internet archives on my smartphone and transferred it to my PC via Bluetooth, read it for 10-15 mins, and then attended a call from a friend while my PC was still on. After a while when I came back PC was in sleep mode I was in hurry so I just pulled the plug out of socket and went on to do my work. It was a common scenario as I did it frequently when I had no time to perform shutdown.

When I returned to power it on again, the Windows logo appeared as usual, but only a black screen was visible after that. I restarted the PC a few times, and the same thing happened every time except when the "Windows can't load properly" message appeared. I ran hardware diagnostics, and the following result appeared on the screen.

```
Test drive:1
Smart check: passed
Short DST: Failed
```

I am not a tech guy, so I didn't understand what was happening.

What is the problem with my PC?
What was the cause?

I don't want to lose some important files, including my course material. How can I get my PC back to its original condition?

Comment: Short DST (Device Self Test) failure likely means that the drive is damaged. I would get an external enclosure to put the drive in and see if it is recoverable on another machine.

Comment: **A** *I don't want to lose some important files, including my course material.* - this is why you copy important data to two or three other places, not just one, for example, USB memory sticks. Make a new copy every time you've made changes that you wouldn't want to make again, and put them in a new folder each time. A better way is a proper backup solution, there is free software available, e.g., Macrium. **B** You should be using at least Windows 10, if at all possible, as it has security updates. **C** If you're not technically-minded, ask your friends about password managers.